# Using .csv as user model in Django

Tags: django, security, csv

I have a django app that works with .csv files as database, in these files i have the users of the system (i can't change that), i need to implement security (a login) in the site. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and you didn't ask for specifics so here is a general overview of what you'll need to do.

If you intend to use django's built-in [authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) then you'll have to setup a database; even if its sqlite. Once you have setup a database, run `manage.py syncdb` to create the necessary authentication tables (by default, the `settings.py` that django creates is already setup for the authentication system, so you don't have to make any other changes).

Once you have that done, you'll have to write a fixture to load the users from the `csv` file into the authentication tables.  You can read up on that in the documentation under [providing initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).

Now you are ready to set passwords and permissions. Your next task will be to make sure that the csv file is in sync with the authentication tables if there a change in the csv file.